# How to manually update catelog price rule magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I was created catalog price rule while before, now i flushed all the price rules from my admin panel.But still my special prices are applying to all catalog products.

So i want to remove these special prices from my catalog.How to refresh or update the price rule manually.

please help me on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

System -> Index Management - Then reindex product prices, or reindex all if they haven't been reindexed in a while, usually it's set to update on save, but flushing rules wouldn't trigger that.

Comment: I reindexed many times ,no luck still special price applying to all products.

Answer (score 0):

Promotions -> Catalog Price Rules **delete rules** and then click on apply rules . its working . i did it . :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is 3 ways
by reindexing.

1. system -> Index Management - Then reindex product prices, or reindex
   all if they haven't been reindexed in a while, usually it's set to
   update.
2. Promotions -> Catalog Price Rules delete rules and then click on apply rules .
3. system->cash management->unable ->delete it 
   4.manually you can del the by var->cash dell all files 
   skypeid:-magento princess.